# Are there prerequisites for a model to be save in keras?

Tags: keras, model, save

I want to save my keras model after the training. The model.fit function works but unfortunately the model.save('path') or model.save_weights('path') commands didn't work.

I have also tried to save the model with pickle or np.save but it didn't work either.

My model is built as follow:

```py
model_resnet = Model(inputs=RESNET.input, outputs=RESNET.output)

model = Sequential()
model.add(model_resnet)
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Reshape((1,256)))

model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(512,return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(512)))

model.add(Dense(11,activation='softmax'))
```

where RESNET is a 3D resnet32 model defined with keras functional API.
The same code can be written like that:

```py
model_ = Sequential()
model_.add(BatchNormalization())
model_.add(Reshape((1,256)))

model_.add(Bidirectional(GRU(512,return_sequences=True)))
model_.add(Bidirectional(GRU(512)))

model_.add(Dense(11,activation='softmax'))

model = Model(input = RESNET.input, outputs = model_(RESNET.output))
```

i am trying to save with the following code:

```py
model.save(root_dir+'\\models\\model.h5')
```

and i also tried:

```py
x = model.get_weights()
with open(root_dir+'\\models\\model.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(x, f)
```

None of these method works.

with the keras save function i had the following error: (dont mind the name of the name of the model in the error)

```
  File ".../train.py", line 110, in <module>
    model_video.save(root_dir+'\\models\\model_video.h5')
  File "...\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1090, in save
    save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
  File "...\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 382, in save_model
    _serialize_model(model, f, include_optimizer)
  File "...\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 114, in _serialize_model
    layer_group[name] = val
  File "...\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\io_utils.py", line 218, in __setitem__
    dataset = self.data.create_dataset(attr, val.shape, dtype=val.dtype)
  File "...\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\group.py", line 136, in create_dataset
    dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(self, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
  File "...\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\dataset.py", line 117, in make_new_dset
    dtype = numpy.dtype(dtype)
TypeError: data type not understood
```

with pickle i have the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../train.py", line 113, in <module>
    pickle.dump(x, f)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'numpy.ndarray'>: it's not the same object as numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: I think both errors show that your numpy installation is somehow broken

Comment: indeed, "conda install numpy" solved the problem.. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"conda install numpy" solved the problem.